# how to compare two alghorithms which one is the fastest in c++

Tags: c++

i want to know which one of my algorithms is the fastest, so i used a code as the one below,i noticed that the time is deferent without using my algorithms, how can i compare two alghorithms which one is the fastest by using small codes like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
clock_t start;
double duration;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  start=clock();
  for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
  for(int k=0;k<100000;k++);//my alghorithm here
  cout<<"duration"<<i+1<<" = "<<(clock()-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
}

}
```

output1 (5.5464s (66.36%) between duration7 and duration5)

```
duration1 = 7.52511
duration2 = 8.06115
duration3 = 7.73809
duration4 = 7.16957
duration5 = 8.3575
duration6 = 4.08989
duration7 = 2.811
duration8 = 3.77779
duration9 = 5.37379
duration10 = 7.94059
```

output2 using register variables

```
duration1 = 1.37294
duration2 = 1.12329
duration3 = 1.26464
duration4 = 1.37525
duration5 = 1.22267
duration6 = 1.43837
duration7 = 1.49671
duration8 = 1.20099
duration9 = 0.813221
duration10 = 1.16527
```

Comment: Have you looked into the many C++ benchmarking libraries such as [Google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)? These libraries exist for this exact purpose.

Comment: Use google benchmark, here is [site where you can try it](http://quick-bench.com/).

Comment: thank you,  CoryKramer,  Marek R.

Comment: m.b you want check bigO of algorithm before manual time test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you didnt not turn on optimizations or the code you posted does not resemble your real code.

In your code you are not using the result of your algorithms, so a compiler would not emit code for calls to your algorithm once you turn on optimizations (assuming the calls themself have no observable side effect). Benchmarking is not trivial because you have to make sure that the compiler does not optimize to much and not too little at the same time, because either way you get meaningless results. Looking at runtimes of a debug-build for example is meaningless.

To make sure that the compile cannot remove the calls to your algorithm you should use its result:

```
int main ()
{
  clock_t start;
  double duration;
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    start=clock();      
    for(int j=0;j<10000;j++) {
       for(int k=0;k<100000;k++) {
          sum += my_alogrithm();
       }
    }
    cout<<"duration"<<i+1<<" = "<<(clock()-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
    return sum; // <-- !!
  }
}
```

Because there are some pitfalls, I would suggest to use some library, or this tool: http://quick-bench.com/